# How concerned should I be about fake art?

Tags: animal-crossing-happy-home-designer

I unlocked the ability to put paintings and such in my customers' homes, which is great, but the game warned me about fakes.

What happens if I put fake art in a home? How can I tell what fake art looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that's just a joke for long-time series fans. I've used several art pieces, often multiple in one home, and never got any messages regarding "fake" art. In fact I've never gotten a single complaint in the entire game outside of not meeting the bare minimum requirements for a building.